# git-ftp - cURL - Maxdownload = -1 * Failed writing body (0 != 131)

Tags: curl, git-ftp

Hey there' I am having problems with git-ftp while trying to 'git ftp init'.

It connects to the server although I am getting error called:

```
* Maxdownload = -1
* Failed writing body (0 != 131)
```

Here is whole thing I get when I use:

```
git ftp init -vv

Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:19 PM: git-ftp version 1.5.1 running on MINGW64_NT-10.0 LAPTOP-VQH0NQNO 2.11.2(0.329/5/3) 2018-11-10 14:38 x86_64 Msys
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:21 PM: Host is 'ftp.****.site'.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:21 PM: User is '****'.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:22 PM: Password is set.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:22 PM: CACert is ''.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:22 PM: Insecure is '0'.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:22 PM: Proxy is ''.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:23 PM: Path is 'public_html/'.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:23 PM: Syncroot is 'c:/xampp/htdocs/hsositetest/'.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:23 PM: The remote sha1 is saved in file '.git-ftp.log'.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:23 PM: Check if curl is functional.
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:23 PM: Check if ftp://****:***@ftp.****.site is accessible.
*   Trying ****...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ftp.****.site (****) port 21 (#0)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 4 of 50 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 18:53. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
< 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
> USER ****
< 331 User **** OK. Password required
> PASS ****
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD public_html
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Extended Passive Mode Entered (|||61618|)
*   Trying ****...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connecting to **** (****) port 61618
* Connected to ftp.****.site (****) port 21 (#0)
> TYPE A
< 200 TYPE is now ASCII
> LIST
< 150 Accepted data connection
* Maxdownload = -1
* Failed writing body (0 != 131)
* Closing connection 0
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 131)
Sun, Jan  6, 2019  6:53:24 PM: fatal: Can't access remote 'ftp://****:***@ftp.****.site', exiting...
```

I have set git-ftp options as:

```
[git-ftp]
    url = ftp://ftp.****.site
    user = ****
    password = ****
    remote-root = public_html
    syncroot = c:/xampp/htdocs/hsositetest/
```

I would appreciate any suggestions, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a blank **.git-ftp.log** and then using git ftp push worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

when git ftp init.

you ftp repository need empty .

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean exactly with that? My server is completely empty but I still get this error :/.

Comment: Please make sure your server is empty, you can query whether there are hidden files; `( ls -a)`

Comment: If you are sure that the server is empty and still can't be initialized, you can manually initialize it by creating a blank **.git-ftp.log** on the server and then overwriting the previous record with the   `git ftp push`.

Comment: @Dealloc Creating git-ftp.log is work very well, problem must be solved